# Sorting Columns From File BASH

Tags: bash, shell, sorting

I have the following shell script that reads in data from a file inputted at the command line.  The file is a matrix of numbers, and I need to separate the file by columns and then sort the columns.  Right now I can read the file and output the individual columns but I am getting lost on how to sort.  I have inputted a sort statement, but it only sorts the first column.

**EDIT:**
I have decided to take another route and actual transpose the matrix to turn the columns into rows.  Since I have to later calculate the mean and median and have already successfully done this for the file row-wise earlier in the script - it was suggested to me to try and "spin" the matrix if you will to turn the columns into rows.

Here is my **UPDATED** code

```
     declare -a col=( )
     read -a line < "$1"
     numCols=${#line[@]}                          # save number of columns

     index=0
     while read -a line ; do
     for (( colCount=0; colCount<${#line[@]}; colCount++ )); do
      col[$index]=${line[$colCount]}
      ((index++))
     done
     done < "$1"

     for (( width = 0; width < numCols; width++ )); do
      for (( colCount = width; colCount < ${#col[@]}; colCount += numCols )    ); do

       printf "%s\t" ${col[$colCount]}
     done
    printf "\n"
   done
```

This gives me the following output:

```
    1 9 6 3 3 6
    1 3 7 6 4 4
    1 4 8 8 2 4
    1 5 9 9 1 7
    1 5 7 1 4 7
```

Though I'm now looking for:

```
    1 3 3 6 6 9
    1 3 4 4 6 7
    1 2 4 4 8 8
    1 1 5 7 9 9
    1 1 4 5 7 7
```

To try and sort the data, I have tried the following:

```
    sortCol=${col[$colCount]}
    eval col[$colCount]='($(sort <<<"${'$sortCol'[*]}"))'
```

Also: (which is how I sorted the row after reading in from line)

```
    sortCol=( $(printf '%s\t' "${col[$colCount]}" | sort -n) )
```

If you could provide any insight on this, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: try looking in the `sort` man page or alternatively search for this in google and look at one of the 100 relevant results.

Comment: I have searched in google and the 100 relevant posts you are talking about actually don't help in my situation.  I have been stuck on this portion of my code for about 2 days now, and the stuff I have found on google wasn't helpful.  I don't know the amount of columns that will be in each file, so I'm not sure how to sort using -k option with an unknown amount.  I have also tried wc -w and -l and things of that sort and that hasn't helped me either.

Comment: I'm sorry, what are you actually trying to do, can you post the expected output ?

Comment: If I read it correctly he is wanting to read/sort/display each column independently of each other. Which there are only 2 approaches I can think of (1) read each column into a separate array and sort, or (2) read/sort each column sequentially, dropping the first column from each successive sort. Neither will look entirely pretty in bash. A nested awk may work as well.

Comment: Post it in the question.

Comment: Sorry to take my frustrations out on you, I am just driving myself crazy with this and am a complete newbie when it comes to bash.  Also I can't use awk unfortunately - I saw that used on alot of the search results from google, but I have to do it using sort.  But yes, I want to sort/display each column independently of one another, and from there I have to compute mean and median, which I have been able to do row-wise, I just can't figure out column-wise

Comment: @user3719014 So you want to calculate mean and median column wise as well as sorting ? Why didn't you put that in the question.

Comment: basically what your script doing is sorting the lines by looking at the first number of eatch line, its equivelent to : `sort -n file` which is normal if you check the sort man page!
your read -a -r col doesn't do much here, maybe you dont need it !
use the -k option to sort each column, for exemple sort -n -k 2 file, will sort the second column

Answer (score 1):

Note, as mentioned in the comments, a pure bash solution isn't pretty. There are a number of ways to do it, but this is probably the most straight forward. The following requires reading all values per line into the array, and saving the matrix `stride` so it can be transposed to read all column values into a row matrix and sorted. All sorted columns are inserted into new row matrix `a2`. Transposing that row matrix yields your original matrix back in column sort order.

**Note** this will work for any rank of column matrix in your file.

```
#!/bin/bash

test -z "$1" && {           ## validate number of input
    printf "insufficient input. usage:  %s <filename>\n" "${0//*\//}"
    exit 1;
}

test -r "$1" || {           ## validate file was readable
    printf "error: file not readable '%s'. usage:  %s <filename>\n" "$1" "${0//*\//}"
    exit 1;
}

## function: my sort integer array - accepts array and returns sorted array
## Usage: array=( "$(msia ${array[@]})" )
msia() {
    local a=( "$@" )
    local sz=${#a[@]}
    local _tmp
    [[ $sz -lt 2 ]] && { echo "Warning: array not passed to fxn 'msia'"; return 1; }
    for((i=0;i<$sz;i++)); do
        for((j=$((sz-1));j>i;j--)); do
        [[ ${a[$i]} -gt ${a[$j]} ]] && {
            _tmp=${a[$i]}
            a[$i]=${a[$j]}
            a[$j]=$_tmp
        }
        done
    done
    echo ${a[@]}
    unset _tmp
    unset sz
    return 0
}

declare -a a1               ## declare arrays and matrix variables
declare -a a2
declare -i cnt=0
declare -i stride=0
declare -i sz=0

while read line; do         ## read all lines into array
    a1+=( $line );
    (( cnt == 0 )) && stride=${#a1[@]}  ## calculate matrix stride
    (( cnt++ ))
done < "$1"

sz=${#a1[@]}                ## calculate matrix size
                            ## print original array
printf "\noriginal array:\n\n"
for ((i = 0; i < sz; i += stride)); do
    for ((j = 0; j < stride; j++)); do
        printf " %s" ${a1[i+j]}
    done
    printf "\n"
done

                            ## sort columns from stride array
for ((j = 0; j < stride; j++)); do
    for ((i = 0; i < sz; i += stride)); do
        arow+=( ${a1[i+j]} )
    done
    a2+=( $(msia ${arow[@]}) )  ## create sorted array
    unset arow
done
                            ## print the sorted array
printf "\nsorted array:\n\n"
for ((j = 0; j < cnt; j++)); do
    for ((i = 0; i < sz; i += cnt)); do
        printf " %s" ${a2[i+j]}
    done
    printf "\n"
done

exit 0
```

**Output**

```
$ bash sort_cols2.sh dat/matrix.txt

original array:

 1 1 1 1 1
 9 3 4 5 5
 6 7 8 9 7
 3 6 8 9 1
 3 4 2 1 4
 6 4 4 7 7

sorted array:

 1 1 1 1 1
 3 3 2 1 1
 3 4 4 5 4
 6 4 4 7 5
 6 6 8 9 7
 9 7 8 9 7
```

Comment: OP said in a comment that the number of columns is unknown.`I don't know the amount of columns that will be in each file`

Comment: Missed that, that is another reason I said it wasn't pretty. Where in the problem statement does it say the columns are of unknown number? I'll give a rework for unknown columns a shot.

Comment: It just says it in a comment, not the actual question.

Comment: Nevermind, I found it in the comment. It will take reading all values into a single matrix and setting a `stride` based on the number of values read in the first line. We'll look at that in the morning.

Answer (score 0):

Awk script

```
awk '
{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)a[i]=a[i]" "$i}      #Add to column array
END{
        for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
                split(a[i],b)          #Split column
                x=asort(b)             #sort column
                for(j=1;j<=x;j++){     #loop through sort
                        d[j]=d[j](d[j]~/./?" ":"")b[j]  #Recreate lines
                }
        }
for(i=1;i<=NR;i++)print d[i]          #Print lines
}' file
```

#### Output

```
1 1 1 1 1
3 3 2 1 1
3 4 4 5 4
6 4 4 7 5
6 6 8 9 7
9 7 8 9 7
```

Comment: My hat's off to the `awk` solution. One issue you can help me with.  Could you provide a brief explanation of the nesting of the loops? Particularly how the `d` designation is filled/initialized? Great solution, I'm just trying to digest it.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin `for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)` loops through the columns/fields. I then split this to create a new array b, which is all the rows/records for that field.Then i loop through b adding `b[j](the field for that row)` to `d[j](the reconstructed record)`. This is within `for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)` so it just adds them to `d`. HTH

Answer (score 0):

Here's my entry in this little exercise. Should handle an arbitrary number of columns. I assume they're space-separated:

```
#!/bin/bash

linenumber=0
while read line; do
        i=0
        # Create an array for each column.
        for number in $line; do
                [ $linenumber == 0 ] && eval "array$i=()"
                eval "array$i+=($number)"
                (( i++ ))
        done    
        (( linenumber++ ))
done <$1
IFS=$'\n'
# Sort each column
for j in $(seq 0 $i ); do
        thisarray=array$j
        eval array$j='($(sort <<<"${'$thisarray'[*]}"))'
done    
# Print each array's 0'th entry, then 1, then 2, etc...
for k in $(seq 0 ${#array0[@]}); do
        for j in $(seq 0 $i ); do
                eval 'printf ${array'$j'['$k']}" "'
        done    
        echo "" 
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Not `bash` but i  think this  `python` code worths a look showing how this task can be achieved using built-in functions.

From the `interpreter`:

```
$ cat matrix.txt 
1 1 1 1 1
9 3 4 5 5
6 7 8 9 7
3 6 8 9 1
3 4 2 1 4
6 4 4 7 7

$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Jun 19 2012, 17:11:17) 
[GCC 4.4.3] on hp-ux11
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
>>> f = open('./matrix.txt')
>>> for row in zip(*[sorted(list(a)) 
               for a in zip(*[a.split() for a in f.readlines()])]):
...    print ' '.join(row)
... 
1 1 1 1 1
3 3 2 1 1
3 4 4 5 4
6 4 4 7 5
6 6 8 9 7
9 7 8 9 7
```